# Safely exiting while loops in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, signals, trap

Say I have a bash script that does:

```
while :
do
    foo
done
```

I would like to be able to run this script from the console and be able to exit it at an arbitrary time as long as it happens in between two runs of foo. So if, say, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (it could be another action that causes the script to exit, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is just an example) that will exit at the next available point after foo is executed:

```
while :
do
    foo
    if [pressed_ctrl_c]:
        break
done
```

Comment: You can look at traps - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm

Comment: Will the "trap <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+c" thing ensure that I am not breaking inside foo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this sort of construct:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
INTR=
trap 'INTR=yes; echo "** INTR **" >&2' INT

while :
do
    (
        # Protect the subshell block
        trap '' INT

        # Protected code here
        echo -n "The date/time is: "
        sleep 2
        date
        read -t2 -p 'Continue (y/n)? ' YN || echo
        test n = "$YN" && echo "Asked for BREAK" >&2 && exit 90
    )
    SS=$?
    test 90 -eq $SS && echo "Matched BREAK" >&2 && break

    # Ctrl/C, perhaps?
    test yes = "$INTR" && echo "Matched INTR" >&2 && break
done
exit 0
```

**Some notes**

- The `read` and `test` pair demonstrates interactive control to the protected code segment inside the `( ... )` block.
- The `exit 90` is the equivalent of `break` but from inside a subshell. The `test 0 != $? ...` line immediately after the subshell block ends is there to capture the `exit 90` status and implement the `break` that the code actually wanted.
- The subshell can use different exit status values to indicate different types of required control flow (`break`, `exit`, etc...)
- This does not prevent a program installing its own signal handler. For example, `gdb` installs its own handler for `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). If the aim is to prevent a user breaking out of the session, changing the interrupt key might help obfuscate the situation (see the code below). Inelegant but potentially effective.

**Changing the SIGINT key on the terminal**

```
G=$(stty -g)                    # Save settings
test -n "$G" && stty intr ^A    # That is caret and A, not Ctrl/A

# ... SIGINT generated with Ctrl/A rather than Ctrl/C ...

test -n "$G" && stty "$G"       # Restore original settings
```

Comment: You haven't addressed the requirement to allow the current invocation of `foo` to run to completion, even if <Ctrl>+<C> has been typed.

Comment: Ah, yes. I'll update the code accordingly, thank you @Scott

Comment: Funny story: That looks a lot like one of my early tries.  I didn’t post it, because it didn’t work — because I typed it into my interactive shell as a one-liner, rather than putting it into a file.  A quick way to test this is to invoke the above script with `source` rather than the normal way.  I think you’ll find that <Ctrl>+<C> has no effect.  I can’t explain it (can you?)  Friendly suggestion: change your `exit 0` to `(exit 0)` (or simply `true`), or this will cause your interactive shell to exit.  … … …  BTW, when you said “capture the `exit 1` status”, did you mean “… `exit 90` status”?

Comment: @Scott, it's intended to be run as part of a script rather than via `source`, mainly because if you try to do stuff with `trap` directly on the command line you can all to easily end up tying yourself in knots. Thank you for `exit 1` - I thought I'd caught them all when I switched to `90` (I felt that this new value was "more obvious" as an escape criterion).

Comment: Yes, I understand that it’s meant to be a script.  I just thought I could debug the script commands faster by doing it on the command line rather than repeatedly editing, saving, and running a script file.  As for tying my shell in knots: I was doing it in parentheses, like `(trap "pressed_ctrl_c=1" INT; while true …)`.  …

Comment: …  As far as magic numbers are concerned, my personal favorites are 17 (index of “Q”, among other things) and 42 ([the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)).  :-)

Comment: This answers my initial question so I have accepted it as an answer, but I'm running into issues when I'm using this with gdb. More precisely, in my case I am running a gdb command in the "protected" shell block. For some reason it looks like the trap command is not protecting gdb from receiving the ctrl + c code. I think what happens then is that gdb spawns a new process (?) which is not covered by trap so it picks up the ctrl + c signal. In turn this exists with code 130 and the whole thing kinda falls through - I am not getting a clean exit

Comment: To be more precise, when running gdb in the "protected" section of the subshell, it still picks up the ctrl+c signal. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: @HenryHenrinson I've updated my Answer to try and address your `gdb` issue. It's not a conclusive fix, though, disappointingly.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
#!/bin/sh
pressed_ctrl_c=
trap "pressed_ctrl_c=1" INT
while true
do
        (trap "" INT; foo)&
        wait  ||  wait
        if [ "$pressed_ctrl_c" ]
        then
                # echo
                break
        fi
done
```

- Initialize `pressed_ctrl_c` to null. 
  This is probably not necessary in a script.
- `trap command signum` tells the shell
  to set up to catch signal number *`signum`*
  and execute *`command`* when it catches one. 
  “INT” is short for “SIGINT” which is short for “interrupt signal”,
  which is the technical term for the signal generated
  by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, so,
  when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
  the shell sets `pressed_ctrl_c` to 1. 
  (SIGINT has a numeric value of 2,
  so you can say `trap "pressed_ctrl_c=1" 2` if you want to economize on typing.)
- Inside the loop, we have a command line in parentheses. 
  This creates a sub-shell.
- We use the `trap` command again. 
  This time *`command`* is a null string;
  this tells the shell to ignore signal number *`signum`*. 
  Since this is inside the parentheses, it affects only the subshell.
- Run `foo`. 
  Since it was run from the subshell,
  `foo` will ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
  i.e., it will keep on running even if you type it.
- Put the subshell in the background ….
- … and wait for it to complete.
- If the `wait` command succeeds, go on to the `if` statement. 
  If it fails, execute another one. 
  (I’ll get back to this.)
- If `$pressed_ctrl_c` is set, break out of the loop. 
  Optionally uncomment the `echo` command
  if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> appears on your terminal as `^C`
  and you want to move to the next line.

We run a command in the background, and then immediately `wait` for it. 
This is very similar to running the command in the foreground
(at least, when done in a script). 
The `wait` command will terminate successfully when the subshell terminates;
i.e., when the `foo` command terminates. 
(The `wait` command will terminate successfully
even if `foo` returns an error.) 
When the first `wait` command terminates successfully,
we skip the second one and go to the `if`.

The shell that’s running the loop is catching interrupts,
but the subshell, and thus the `foo` process, are ignoring them. 
So, when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
the shell sets `pressed_ctrl_c` to 1 and aborts the (first) `wait` command. 
Since the first `wait` command failed, we go on to the second one. 
Remember, the `foo` subshell is still running,
so this `wait` still has something to do
(i.e., it will wait for the `foo` to finish.)

Finally, if the variable has been set to indicate
that a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> has been pressed while `foo` was running,
break output the loop.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice,
the second one will interrupt and abort the second `wait` command. 
This will cause your script to terminate and return you to your shell prompt,
while leaving `foo` running in the background. 
You can mitigate this by saying `wait  ||  wait  ||  wait  ||  wait`;
extending it as far as you want. 
You would need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> once for each `wait`
to terminate the script prematurely.

#### D’oh!

A problem with this is that processes that are put into the background
by a script have their standard input set to `/dev/null`. 
If your `foo` reads from the keyboard, the above will need revision.